# unable to get edited textbox value from a gridview while updating gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

while updating textbox in gridview. in update event im just getting old value / database value not edited value . how to get edited text field value in rowupdating event

aspx code

```
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SMS Sender">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SmsSender")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSmsSender" runat="server" MaxLength="6" Text='<%#Eval("SmsSender") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

.cs code

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        string sendername = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtSmsSender")).Text;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I HAVE TO ADD

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetSMSSender();

        }
```

it was binding in pageload in update event. so value again changing. in page load i have to write this.